# Wordpress MU: www. to the http://

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wildcard

In my .htaccess what would I have to put in it to basically create a wildcard so if anyone accesses `www.*.domain.co.nz` it will redirect to `http://*.domain.co.nz`.

I can get it working for one domain but then I clicked what about the others.

At this stage I have an `index.html` being a hold page but I would also like to be able to access wordpress's `index.php`

I am using the standard MU `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%2/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You'll want to put this right below `RewriteBase /` in your htaccess file.